# Open suggestion of all installed email clients to user

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a use case to send email to external users from my app.

We want to show all installed email clients when user clicks on send mail which open the user opted mail client with pre filled fields.

How can I achieve this?

Ex : it is like when user clicks on share button of image in gallery, we will show all apps which supports file sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the UIActivityViewController is what you're looking for?

http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/